# understanding comparator in Collections.max

Tags: java, collections, comparator

Can somebody please explain what the following lines of code mean?. I had a hard time understanding the Comparator part.I tried googling but all of them were too complex for me to understand. Could somebody please explain it in simpler way?

```
String maxLengthString = Collections.max(dateStrings, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()));
```

Comment: It's nothing special. We are making use of Java streams on the list where the comparator picks one element at a time,that is, a String and checks on its length. So, here the elements of the list are getting compared with their lengths to give the longest element

Comment: Which parts of it do you already understand?

Comment: Till .max(dateStrings,

Comment: *Lambda. Sorry 

Comment: Huh, am I right its just finding string from the list, which has the max length, right? While found, it is stored in `maxLengthString` variable, right? Thanks :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `max` method returns the element that is considered the "biggest" in the collection.

In this case, you have a collection of strings. By default, strings are compared alphabetically. When you order strings alphabetically, the ones at the top are considered strings that has a smaller value, while the ones at the bottom are considered strings that has a larger value.

However, whoever wrote the code in your question does not want to compare strings that way. He/she wants to compare strings by their lengths. So a longer string will mean a "bigger" string.

You can pass in a second argument to `max` specifying how you want to compare the strings. Since you want to compare them by length, you pass in:

```
Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length())
```

Some useful things you might find helpful:

- [docs for `comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)
- [docs for `max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator))
- [what lambda expressions are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: @ArunGowdru You can transform the string into whatever comparable thing you like. For (an absurd) example, you can count how many "a"s are there in the string and compare them! Just put the logic of that in the lambda expression in `comparing` and return the value you want to compare.

Comment: Idk if it sounds cool but writing "the ones at the top are "small" strings, while the ones at the bottom are "big" strings" might confuse some.

Comment: @AakashVerma What about now? What do you suggest I could put there?

Comment: @Sweeper Better. You might wanna check the comments section of assylias's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you call:

```
String max = Collections.max(dateStrings);
```

You will get the maximum string in the collection, using the natural order of strings. In other words, it will be the largest *in lexicographical order*. So if the list contains "aa", "bb", zz", "cc", max will be "zz".

Your example wants to retrieve the longest string in the list. So you need to provide a custom comparator that will compare the strings based on their length.

Comment: Would lexicographical be a better term here?

Comment: I need the date which is latest of all. Will removing comparator part solve this?

Comment: @Arun Gowdru No, for that you need the Date objects inside the list for a proper date with date comparison and not the String. Any class that has Comparable interface or Comparator implemented can be directly fed to Collections comparator. If you're working on native Date object, it will be fine without that lambda part. Else, you have to define your own Comparator.